# href link that's generated via ECHO from php is adding "â€‹" to the end of the destination URL

Tags: php

for some reason when you click the click to register like below:

```
if(!$_COOKIE["user"])
{
    echo "<a href=\"http://www.cinicraft.com/linacard/adminLogin.php\">Login</a>"; 
    echo "/<a href=\"http://www.cinicraft.com/linacard/adminRegister​\">Register</a>";
}
```

It will add â€‹ at the end of the URL

So when I click on Login it correctly brings you to "adminLogin.php" but when you click on register it directs you to "adminRegister.phpâ€‹". I'm not really sure how to fix this since I can't figure out exactly where the "â€‹" comes from.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What page encoding are you using?

Comment: gettin `â` means you've got a charset mismatch. e.g. UTF-8 text being output into an ISO-8859 environment. You must use the same character set throughout your entire rendering pipeline, or connect the stages with appropriate translation logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try using single quotes instead.

```
if(!$_COOKIE["user"])
{
    echo '<a href="http://www.cinicraft.com/linacard/adminLogin.php">Login</a>'; 
    echo '<a href="http://www.cinicraft.com/linacard/adminRegister.php​">Register</a>';
}
```

Will save all the \" - should also make this work.